# How do I specify associations in Rails that pass through several models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, tags, tagging, polymorphic-associations

I'm writing some tricky polymorphic relationships to handle tagging.

I have a `Tag` model, and a `Tagging` model which belongs_to a polymorphic `taggable`.

I have an `Item` model, which `has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable`, and `has_many :tags, :through => :taggings`, so that I can call `@item.tags`.

This is all working ok.

I want to bring another model into the mix - a `Store` which `has_many :items`. I want to be able to find all tags associated with all items in the store using `@store.tags`.

Here's what I have:

```
class Store < AR::Base
  has_many :items
  has_many :tags, :through => :items, :source => :taggings
```

However, this returns all of the `taggings` associated with items in the store, not the actual tags.

How do I get specify that the store has_many tags, through items, through taggings?

Can post more info if needed - trying to prevent information overload! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source for a `has_many` association must be a `belongs_to`, `has_one`, or `has_many` association *without* a `:through` option (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926536/invalid-source-reflection-macro-has-many-through) for info).

There is [a plugin](http://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through) that some people have had success with, but in my case it didn't seem to work correctly with my `taggable` polymorphic association.

At the moment, my solution is to pass a `finder_sql` option to `has_many`:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_many :tags, :finder_sql => 
    'SELECT tags.* from tags
      INNER JOIN taggings on tags.id = taggings.tag_id
      INNER JOIN items on items.id = taggings.taggable_id AND taggings.taggable_type = "Item"
      WHERE items.store_id = #{id}'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in plain Ruby:

```
site.wares.map(&:tags).flatten.uniq
```

This will be inefficient though, unless you have a low number of tags / wares / items.