# Rails or SQL to get through a few model associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm a bit of a n00b when it comes to hacking my own SQL for my ruby on rails app, so your help would be much appreciated. I have a model as follows:

```
Timetable 
    has_many :enrollments

Enrollment 
    belongs_to :timetable 
    belongs_to :stream 
    has_one :course, :through => stream
    #Stream & Timetable together are unique for an Enrollment

Stream 
    has_many :enrollments 
    belongs_to :course

Course 
    has_many :streams
```

i.e

`Timetable 1-* Enrollments *-1 Stream *-1 Course`

I'm trying to find the best way to get a set of courses associated with a timetable, through it's enrollments, through each enrollment's streams, which have a course.

Preferably something like:

```
Timetable.courses
```

Trying the following had no luck

```
Timetable
    has_many :courses, :through => :enrollments, :source => :course
```

It gave me an error `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationMacroError: Invalid source reflection macro :has_one :through for has_many :courses, :through => :enrollments.  Use :source to specify the source reflection.`

I took a look at [Invalid source reflection macro :has_many :through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926536/invalid-source-reflection-macro-has-many-through) and it seemed to be pretty close.

I also found http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/has-many-through-habtm.html but I can't quite grasp how to apply this here (although it is 12am NZT, so maybe that's why!).

Help, hints or even the answer would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is the SQL you want (for example):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM courses c
  LEFT JOIN streams s ON s.course_id = c.id
  LEFT JOIN enrollments e ON e.stream_id = s.id
  LEFT JOIN timetables t ON e.timetable_id = t.id
WHERE t.id = 5
```

To achieve this in rails, have a look at

```
Course.joins(:streams => {:enrollments => :timetables}).to_sql
```

This shows you the sql it generates. You can then apply other conditions like so

```
Course.joins(:streams => {:enrollments => :timetables}).where(some condition on timetables)
```

Comment: That SQL does the trick nicely! Will try to wrap my head around the rails way of doing it :) Cheers @mosch!

Comment: For any future readers, I ended up adding `Stream has_many timetables, :through => :enrollments`. That lets me simply call `Course.joins(:streams => :timetables).where("timetable_id = **id**").group('timetables.id')` to get a set of Courses for a given timetable! :)